# How can I add/destroy new objects to existing formation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FormationsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform squadMemeberPrefab;
    public int numberOfSquadMembers = 20;
    public int columns = 4;
    public int gaps = 10;
    public Formations formations;

    private int numofmembers;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        numofmembers = numberOfSquadMembers;
        formations.Init(numberOfSquadMembers, columns, gaps);
        GenerateSquad();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (numofmembers != numberOfSquadMembers)
        {
            GenerateSquad();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateSquad()
    {
        Transform go = squadMemeberPrefab;

        for (int i = 0; i < formations.newpositions.Count; i++)
        {
            go = Instantiate(squadMemeberPrefab);
            go.position = formations.newpositions[i];
            go.tag = "Squad Member";
            go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Formations script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Formations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> newpositions;

    private int numberOfSquadMembers;
    private int columns;
    private int gaps;
    private List<Quaternion> quaternions;

    private Vector3 FormationSquarePositionCalculation(int index)
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * gaps;
        float posY = (index / columns) * gaps;
        return new Vector3(posX, posY);
    }

    private void FormationSquare()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquadMembers; i++)
        { 
            Vector3 pos = FormationSquarePositionCalculation(i);
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
            newpositions.Add(position);
        }
    }

    public void Init(int numberOfSquadMembers, int columns, int gaps)
    {
        this.numberOfSquadMembers = numberOfSquadMembers;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.gaps = gaps;
        FormationSquare();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is in the FormationsManager in the Update not only just calling GenerateSquad but to add the new once to the last/next position of the existing already formation.

```
void Update()
        {
            if (numofmembers != numberOfSquadMembers)
            {
                GenerateSquad();
            }
        }
```

If the value of numberOfSquadMembers is 20 first time and then I changed it to 21 add new object to the end of the formation and same if I change the value of numberOfSquadMembers for example from 20 to 19 or from 21 to 5 destroy the amount of objects from the end and keep the formation shape.

[image: Formation]

The soldiers the last line is on the right side.
So if I change the value to add more then add it to the right and if I change to less destroy from the right side. The most left line of soldiers is the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you keep GameObject instances inside FormationsManager class, and then reuse them in GenerateSquad method.

In FormationsManager class, add and modify code as follows.

```
public GameObject squadMemeberPrefab;
List<GameObject> SquadMembers = new List<GameObject>();

void Update()
{
    if (numofmembers != numberOfSquadMembers)
    {
        numofmembers = numberOfSquadMembers;
        formations.Init(numberOfSquadMembers, columns, gaps);
        GenerateSquad();
    }
}

private void GenerateSquad()
{
    Transform go = squadMemeberPrefab;
    List<GameObject> newSquadMembers = new List<GameObject>();

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < formations.newpositions.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < SquadMembers.Count)
            go = SquadMembers[i];
        else
        {
            go = Instantiate(squadMemeberPrefab);
            newSquadMembers.Add(go);
        }
        go.position = formations.newpositions[i];
        go.tag = "Squad Member";
        go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }

    for (; i < SquadMembers.Count; i++)
        Destroy(SquadMembers[i]);

    SquadMembers = newSquadMembers;
}
```

However, I recommend you to consider GameObject Pool (Object Pool), which can thoroughly resolve such object recycle problem. For this purpose, you can use ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler. Go to [this Unity Documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html) and search  text "GameObject pool". You can see an example code there.

Comment: This is working I had to change the line public Transform squadMemeberPrefab; to public GameObject squadMemeberPrefab; and also to add to the newSquadMembers List: newSquadMembers.Add(go); inside the loop. Now it's working great. Now I will go to look how to work with the Object Pool.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi, yeah, that's right. I forgot an important line. I edited my answer. good luck on your object pool ;)